# VS2017 webdeploy password ignored

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy

Visual Studio 2017 is ignoring the saved password when I attempt a web deploy.

This is my sequence of operations.

1. Bring up the Publish dialog so I can edit the publish profile.
2. Set a password.
3. Change the value of the Save Password checkbox at least once, ending with it being ticked.
4. Validate Connection successfully.
5. Click the Next button in case this is required to harvest UI values.
6. Click the Save button.
7. Inspect the blah.pubxml and blah.pubxml.user files to verify that it VS thinks it is saving a password and the user file contains an encrypted password

Everything appears to be in order yet still I am prompted for a password. How have I sinned that I deserve such punishment, and what must I do to be forgiven?

Comment: with visual studio, you never know. nor the source of the sin, nor its duration or when its going to expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once blah.pubxml.user contains an encrypted password and blah.pubxml is set to use it, close right out of Visual Studio.

When you reload Visual Studio and your project you will find that you are no longer prompted for a password. Visual Studio is caching stuff somewhere.